# Lifecycle of variable in AMD module

Tags: requirejs, backbone-views

Below is the code which I saved as a file named *listView.js*. I wonder about how the inner variable working. For example, variable `dtRngPckr` is defined in the initialize within `Backbone.View` and whenever application move to the other part, I called onClose function to null the said variable. And when I need to reuse this module, there must be an error occur in render function. It triggered error not a function

```
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";
    var $        = require('jquery'),
        _        = require('underscore'),
        Backbone = require('backbone'),
        dtRngPckr;

    return Backbone.View.extend({
       initialize: function (opt) {
           dtRngPckr = require('daterangepicker');
       },
       render: function () {
          dtRngPckr();
       },
       onClose: function () {
          dtRngPckr = null;
       }
    });
});
```

Could someone tell me how's exactly this variable working

Comment: Can you put a link in your question to the library you are loading with `require('daterangepicker')`?

Comment: https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequireJS caches the return value of a module so it only has to fetch it once, all prior variables are shared between the instances. To use a separate `daterangepicker` for each instance, you could attach it to your view:

```
return Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function (opt) {
       this.dtRngPckr = require('daterangepicker');
   },
   render: function () {
      this.dtRngPckr();
   },
   onClose: function () {
      this.dtRngPckr = null;
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks. Attach it to view is the best way. I think this might be the solution for now.